# Dynamically joining strings

Tags: python

I have this string `https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500`. I want to concatenate this string with the other string `&filters[city]=Mumbai&filters[polutant_id]=PM10`. The second string should be added dynamically based on the dictionary below.

```
criteria = {'city':["Mumbai","Delhi"], 'polutant_id': ["PM10", "NO2"]}
```

The output below contains 4 strings as the above dictionary has 4 possible combination of city and polutant_id.

**Output**

```
"https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filters[city]=Mumbai&filters[polutant_id]=PM10"

"https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filters[city]=Delhi&filters[polutant_id]=PM10"

"https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filters[city]=Mumbai&filters[polutant_id]=NO2"

"https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filters[city]=Delhi&filters[polutant_id]=NO2"
```

**What I tried**

In order to get all the possible combinations I am using the function below -

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

def expand_grid(data_dict):
    rows = itertools.product(*data_dict.values())
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=data_dict.keys())

criteriaAll = expand_grid(criteria)
```

To fetch filters, using the code below -

```
['&filters[' + ls+ ']=' for ls in list(criteria.keys())]
```

I am stuck in achieving the desired output. **Note -** Dictionary can have more or less than 2 keys.

Comment: You are only iterating over the keys of the dictionary. Iterate over its `.items()` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Python. I just tried with .items( ) but getting error --- TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

Comment: Can you post the content for `data_dict` variable and also which version of python you are using?

Comment: @RamonMoraes content for data_dict is in the post. Look for 'criteria' dictionary. I am using Python 3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need the complexity of a dataframe to solve this. First create a list of tuples of key/value pairs from criteria, then take the cartesian product of that list and iterate the tuples in the product to produce the filter strings:

```py
base = 'https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500'
criteria = {'city':["Mumbai","Delhi"], 'polutant_id': ["PM10", "NO2"]}
criteriaAll = [[(k, v) for v in criteria[k]] for k in criteria]
result = [base + ''.join(f'&filter[{ls}]={value}' for ls, value in p) for p in itertools.product(*criteriaAll)]
```

Output:

```
[
 'https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filter[city]=Mumbai&filter[polutant_id]=PM10',
 'https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filter[city]=Mumbai&filter[polutant_id]=NO2',
 'https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filter[city]=Delhi&filter[polutant_id]=PM10',
 'https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filter[city]=Delhi&filter[polutant_id]=NO2'
]
```